# localhost not showing /import

Tags: 7, feeds

If I navigate to `http://localhost:8080/import` I am taken back to the index page.

If I navigate to `http://localhost:8080/?q=import` I am take to the import page.

If I navigate to `http://localhost:8080/admin` I am taken to the list of admin options.

The webserver for localhost is the default one that comes with Phpstorm (in ubuntu 14.04), which is the built in webserver that comes with php5.4 and above.

When deployed to a remote server `/import` works.

What might cause this issue?

Comment: What happens if you visit `http://localhost:8080/admin/config/search/clean-urls`, there may be some errors present, etc.

Comment: No errors that I can see, http 200 everywhere. I just get the page.

Comment: Anything point the way on the status report page? Any errors in watchdog or the server log?

Comment: nothing on the status report page. nothing in the watchdog log. I'm running through Phpstorm, and that isn't reporting any errors.

Comment: Have you modified your .htaccess file? Try loading fresh one from Drupal just to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to eliminate a possible cause of your problem, and **assuming your web server is Apache**: make sure the `mod_rewrite` module is enabled. If it is not, then enable it and restart Apache.

To verify this, open the file `httpd.conf` inside your Apache installation folder and find the line starting with `AllowOverride`:

**If** that line looks like `AllowOverride None`

**Then**:

1. edit it to look like so: `AllowOverride All`
2. and afterwards restart Apache.

If you're using PHP Storm (as mentioned now in the further edited question), it might help to try what is documented in [Disabling clean URLs](https://www.drupal.org/node/5590). Here is a quote about that page:

> It's possible that a Drupal site that was once configured to run with clean URLs later on stops doing so. After that, almost all content is inaccessible, because the paths being generated are not supported by the hosting platform.

Comment: My webserver is the one that comes with phpstorm. This is the built in webserver that comes with php5.4 and above.

Comment: Thx for extending your question! Refer to my updated answer now also. Does that help?

Comment: Great! Would you mind adding a small extra comment please with a few more details about your specific case?